# Why is it that the following function in JS compiles without errors although it won't execute because of a missing return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So in this app I'm making, there's this function that I was writing incorrectly:

```
export const setCurrentUser = ( user ) => { 
    createAction(USER_ACTION_TYPES.SET_CURRENT_USER, user)
}
```

I mistakenly added the squiggly brackets but missed the return statement within, so the function was not working, but compiled without mistakes. Once I removed the brackets, it worked because of the implicit return. Shouldn't it throw a warning or an error for writing a function that wouldn't return anything? It took me ages to debug (I'm kind of a noob) because it was compiling without errors or warnings.

Comment: Learn and use TypeScript, and typo-like problems like these will become a thing of the past 95% of the time

Comment: Or, use a function declaration instead so that returns are more defined. Devs have been using function expressions for ages now when they don't really fit the purpose. Adding TS to the mix will only confuse matters. IMO.

Comment: "*but compiled without mistakes*" JS is not a compiled language. It will not warn you ahead of time of something being wrong. It *might* throw an error at runtime if there is a syntax error, for example. With that said, there is no syntax error here. The code you've typed is *valid*. "*Shouldn't it throw a warning or an error for writing a function that wouldn't return anything?*"  Why would JS warn you it's not? There is no "read the mind of the programmer" instructions when executing the code. Void functions are perfectly valid code.

Comment: As far as the language is concerned, there is no error in this function as Javascript does not require a return statement in a function.  This code is perfectly valid Javascript.  The fact that you want to return a value here is just your own programming mistake, not something the language can know.

Comment: I just noticed the title: "*although it won't execute because of a missing return*"  - it absolutely does execute, even without a return. There is literally no error in this code. The only error might be if you tried to call `setCurrentUser(someUser).andSomePropertyHere` which is *not* a problem with the code you've shown here.